# Get text and id from an li element on click with pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I've been stuck with this for several days and I can't solve it.

I've done it with jQuery with no problem, but I need it in pure JS.

This is how my list is generated.

```
function get_friends(items){


if(items != undefined){
    if (items.length != 0){
        var html_friends_list = "";

        for(var count = 0; count < items.length; count++){
            if(items[count].subscription == "both"){
                var display_name = Strophe.getNodeFromJid(items[count].jid);

                html_friends_list = html_friends_list + "<li style='font-size:19px' id='open_chat-" + items[count].jid + "'>" + "<a href='chat-js/index.html'>" + display_name + "<span class='block-list-label' id='" + items[count].jid  + "_unread_messages" + "'>0</span><span class='block-list-label' id='" + items[count].jid  + "_change_status" + "'></span></a></li>";

             }
        }

        document.getElementById("friends-list").innerHTML = html_friends_list;
```

As a said I want to save the value of the text and the id of any li element clicked.

Regards

Comment: And where is the click event over `li` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't specified whether this is for a specific list or just any `li` on your page.  The below will log the id and innerHTML components of any `li` on the page.  Perhaps you may need to update the `querySelector` for your particular use case.

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('li');

Array.prototype.slice.call(list).forEach(function(listItem){
  listItem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9gdrzeL/1/) which I think demonstrates what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This answer is almost perfect. The only problem is that I need the text node of the list and with innerHTML I'm also getting every tag (span, a). How can I avoid that and just get the text?

Comment: It depends on what part of the text in the ```li``` you are specifically after but you can use ```this.childNodes[0].nodeValue``` to retrieve the text values within the ```li```.  You may need to look at trying different childnodes (i.e. using different values instead of **0**) to retrieve the specific text you require.

Comment: I've tried and with 0 it gives me a null, and with any other number it doesn't even give me an alert. I want to get the text shown in the list. In my question, the variable **display_name**

Comment: Can you give an example of one of ```li```s that gets generated from your function and specify which bit of text you are after?

Comment: <li id="example"> <a href='chat-js/index.html'> **TEXT WANTED** <span class="example" id="example"> **TEXT WANTED** </span><span class="example" id="example"></span></a></li>

Comment: If there's any way of getting just the first **text wanted**   without a slice it would be perfect.

Comment: Ahh, apologies I thought you were after specific bits of text.  You can just use either **this.textContent** or **this.innerText** to retrieve all of the text.  There are a couple of older browser limitations with these (see http://caniuse.com/#search=textcontent and http://caniuse.com/#search=innertext to compare).  I updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9gdrzeL/2/) to demonstrate this.

Comment: No worries, that was perfect. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7uzm0eu/2/)

Combination of james' answer and working example.

```
function get_friends(items) {
    if (items != undefined) {
        if (items.length != 0) {
            var html_friends_list = "<ul>";

            for (var count = 0; count < items.length; count++) {

                if (items[count].subscription == "both") {

                    html_friends_list = html_friends_list + "<li id='open_chat-" + items[count].jid + "'>"+ items[count].display_name +"</li>";

                }

            }
                        html_friends_list = html_friends_list + '</ul>'
            document.getElementById("friends-list").innerHTML = html_friends_list;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you should trigger prototype after your dom element created.

Comment: As I said to James, both of your answers are almost perfect but I'm having the problem that I tell him in his answer.